# Converting dataset into HDF5 file

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, hdf5, google-colaboratory

I wanna convert a facial expressions dataset into a HDF5 file and I don't know how exactly to do it.

from [here](http://www.machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/data_preparation/hdf5/hdf5.html) I know how to do it with a cat-vs-dog dataset but I wanna know how it's done in general.

(My purpose of all these is to speed up my CNN model training process in google colaboratory and I tried this by mounting google drive and consequently reading my dataset from google drive but it was too slow to train my model (even slower than my pc !) ).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to import package `h5py`

```
import h5py
```

Then, open a file with `hdf5` format like this:

```
with h5py.File(os.path.join(output_folder, 'file_name' + '.hdf5'), 'a') as h:
// process file here as normal
```

For detailed information, refer the function `create_input_files` [here](https://github.com/luulinh90s/Show-Attend-and-Tell-Pytorch-Implementation/blob/master/utils.py) to know more, or you can clone the repo and run `python create_input_files` to see how this function actually works and how to create `hdf5` files.